# Single Page Application classList issue

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application

I am creating my first SPA and im following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlVmmsMD28w&t=846s , just i found it the most recent one and most informative.

Everything is working if I do like him, but as soon as I change it to my html, i get this error ( **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null** ) as soon as I am pressing on anchor tag.

```
// object
const app = {
pages: [], // property to save pages in
show: new Event('show'),
init: function() {
    app.pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');
    //listener for show event, calling function
    app.pages.forEach((pg)=> {
        pg.addEventListener('show', app.pageShown);
    })

    //listener for click event, calling function
    document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link').forEach((link)=>{
        link.addEventListener('click', app.nav);
    })
    // showing on which page we are in the tab
    history.replaceState({}, 'Home', '#home');
    // handling the "back" button
    window.addEventListener('popstate', app.poppin);
},

nav: function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    let currentPage = ev.target.getAttribute('data-target');
    document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active'); ////////// THE LINE ERROR IS APPEARING AT
    document.getElementById(currentPage).classList.add('active');
    console.log(currentPage);
    history.pushState({}, currentPage, '#${currentPage}');
    document.getElementById(currentPage).dispatchEvent(app.show);
},
pageShown: function(ev){
    console.log('Page', ev.target.id, 'just shown');
},
poppin: function(ev){
    console.log(location.hash, 'popstate event');
}
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', app.init);
```

and this is my html code:

```
<div class="page selected" id="home">
<div id="cell_1">
    <a href="#" data-target="recipe" class="nav-link">
        <img id="mainPic" src="./pictures/thai.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page" id="recipe">
<p>a</p>
</div>
```

Can anyone try to help me why this is happening? By the way im not getting redirected to other page as well.

Comment: The error means that `document.querySelector('.active')` returns `null`, meaning that there is no element on the page with the class "active".

Answer (score 0):

The line `document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');` is throwing because this part `document.querySelector('.active')` is returning `null`
and then `.classList` is being called on `null` rather than the a matching element.

You can fix this by checking to see if anything was returned before calling attempting to remove the `active` class.

```js
// first look for a element with the class active
const activeElement = document.querySelector('.active');
// if found then remove the 'active' class
activeElement && activeElement.classList.remove('active');
```

[MDN's querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) documentation can provide you with more insight.

Comment: I got to the point where it gets me to another page but as I console.log(currentPage), it shows me its "null". I dont get it. There is a function to "nav" in which currentPage get attribute from "data-target" which supposed to be "recipe", but its still returning null.
I dont get this...

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was hidden in the "current page". 
As it was always returning null for me i started digging in here and ended up that all I needed was to get .currentTarget instead of .target in "nav" function.

how it was:

```
let currentPage = ev.Target.getAttribute('data-target');
```

how it has to be:

```
let currentPage = ev.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-target');
```

Back button is still struggling, but atleast main thing is working. Thanks for the help.